# Detection Method - powershell - registry

Tags: powershell

I am working with figuring out how to create a detection method in SCCM. I have been using the method below which works. But I need a little more into

```
if(test-path -path <regpath>)


{
Write-Host "installed"
}

else
{
}
```

I am looking to use where -Name DisplayVersion -eq "7.7.1" for the detection method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to use `get-itemproperty`.

Comment: i am but i don't know how to use the value of displayversion for "xxxx".
Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\xxxx' | select DisplayVersion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58419999/45375) works well, even in older versions of PowerShell, but it requires duplication of the value name.

In **PowerShell v5 or higher** you can use the **`Get-ItemPropertyValue` cmdlet** instead, which avoids the duplication:

```
$key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\xxx'
$valueName = 'DisplayVersion' # in PS terminology: *property* name 
$valueData = '7.7.1' # in PS terminology: *property value*

if ((Get-ItemPropertyValue $key $valueName) -eq $valueData) {
  "installed"
} else {
  "NOT installed"
}
```

---

If, instead, you're **looking for specific property value (registry-value data) in a given property (registry value) *among all the subkeys*** of a given registry key path:

```
$key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
$valueName = 'DisplayVersion'
$valueData = '7.7.1'

if (Get-ChildItem $key | Where { $_.GetValue($valueName) -eq $valueData }) {
  "installed"
} else {
  "NOT installed"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So predefining variables first is a whole lot easier to understand what I am wanting to do/look for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
if ((get-itemproperty hkcu:\key1 name1).name1 -eq 'value1') { 
  'yes' 
}
```